# calculating segment adresses

Tags: assembly, intel, memory-segmentation

in intel 8086 , given a physical adress how to find the possible sets of segment : offset
for example :
5F173 = (5F17,3) = (578D,78A3)

when the first is easy to find but what about the second ?
and is the offset always represented in 16 bits because i've found this two examples :
5F173 = (5F17,3) and (578DE,0E) and i'm confused about the bits representing each offset : 8 for the first and 16 for the second (?)

Comment: As segment is 65536 bytes and paragraph is 16 bytes, you have 65536/16=4096 variants.

Comment: `0003h` fits in 16 bits.  Writing it as `3` doesn't change that.  But `(578DE,0E)` is nonsense; that's showing a 5-hex-digit (20-bit) segment, and `(seg<<4) + off` would give the low digit (nibble) of the linear address as `Eh` not `3`.  Anyway, there isn't one unique way to break down a 20-bit linear address into logical (seg:off) with two 16-bit components; there are I think 2^12 different ways for each address, except at the very edges of address space (the bottom and top).  Common choices are to put 16 bits in one and 4 bits in the other.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry i meant 578DE = (578D,0E)